# c# Regex inside some html tag

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying during some hour with regex to take text inside some html tag:

```
<div class="ewok-rater-header-section">
  <ul class="header">

        <li><h1>meow</h1></li>

        <li><h1>meow2</h1></li>

        <li><h1>Time = <span class="work-weight">9.0 minutes</span></h1></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

i take `meow` with

```
var regexpost = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"<h1(.*?)>(.*?)</h1>");
var mpost = regexpost.Match(reqpost);
string lechat = (mpost.Groups[2].Value).ToString();
```

but not other
I like to add `meow` in a `textbox` , `meow2` in a second textbox and 9.0 (minutes) in a last one

Comment: Although regex could easily solve this problem in this specific circumstance. It truely is not the right tool for the job. if you need to parse html, its best to use a tool that understands html and can easily process it. like html agility pack... http://html-agility-pack.net/  i

Comment: (?![\s]|.*=.*)(?<=\>)([^><]+)(?=\<)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3010968

Answer (score 1):

In these situations a Html parser can help a lot, and can also be a lot more precise and robust

[Html Agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/selectors)

**Example**

```
var html = @"<div class=""ewok-rater-header-section"">
               <li><h1>meow</h1></li>
               <li><h1>meow2</h1></li>
               <li><h1>Time = <span class=""work-weight"">9.0 minutes</span></h1></li>
            </div>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

// you can search for the heading
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li//h1"))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Found heading : " + node.InnerText);
}

// or you can be more specific
var someSpan = doc.DocumentNode
                  .SelectNodes("//span[@class='work-weight']")
                  .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Found span : " + someSpan.InnerText);
```

**Output**

```
Found heading : meow
Found heading : meow2
Found heading : Time = 9.0 minutes
Found span : 9.0 minutes
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNr7LA)

Answer (score 0):

it s for parse http reponse. Then is it not slow to use a html parser to create document ?